# Rails loop through objects in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following associations:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opening_hours
end

class OpeningHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

I'm looping through shops inside a view like this:

```
<% @shop.each do |shop|%>
  <%= shop.street %>
  <%= shop.city %>
<% end %>
```

I have an action inside a controller, from which I want to check if a shop is open or not:

```
def open
  @open = OpeningHour.where(day: Time.zone.now.wday).where('? BETWEEN opens AND closes', Time.zone.now).any?
end
```

I would like to show if the shop is open or not with something like this:

```
<% if %>
  <span style="color: black">Open</span>
<% else %>
  <span style="color: lightgrey">Close</span>
<% end %>
```

How can I add the above `if` and `else` to the loop in order to show if each shop is open or close?

Comment: Is your `OpeningHour` model not related to `Shop`?

Comment: How does your 'open' method know which shop's times to use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @16kb I just added the associations of the both models to my original question

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ SteveTurczyn ! that is exactly what I'm trying to figure out... and how to implement it according to the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `opening_hours` belong to the `shop` model

```
class Shop
  def open?
    opening_hours.where(day: Time.zone.now.wday).where('? BETWEEN opens AND closes', Time.zone.now).any?
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<% if shop.open? %>
    <span style="color: black">Open</span>
<% else %>
    <span style="color: lightgrey">Close</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Beat me to it; Worth pointing out again to the author that these types of methods do NOT belong in controllers but in the models.